# How can I fix my code to correctly print "Hello World!"

Tags: .net

I have some code that I need to fix to print "Hello World!".  For some reason it prints the letters all scrambled.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim s As String = "Hello World!"
    Parallel.For(0, s.Length, Sub(i)
                                Console.Write(s(i))
                              End Sub)
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Now *who* edited the code to be all muxed up? (Reverting)

Comment: It's right there below the question: Shoban did, and I thank him for that.

Comment: @SpiffySponge: This is a very bad formatting with so many spaces and empty lines.

Comment: @Matten - Thank you for your opinion.  I *really* appreciate it.

Comment: It's not so much about the code spacing as it is the fact that whoever edited it *screwed it up* by misplacing parenthesis.  If you're going to edit something at least take a little care in your editing endeavors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the ParallelOptions parameter and specify the degree of parallelism you require.  In this case you don't require parallelism.

```
Sub Main()

        Dim s As String = "Hello World!"

        Dim p As New ParallelOptions()
        p.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
        p.TaskScheduler = Nothing
        p.CancellationToken = Nothing

        Parallel.For(0, s.Length, p, Sub(i)

                                         Console.Write(s(i))

                                     End Sub)

        Console.Read()

    End Sub
```

Comment: There is really no reason to use `Parallel` here. An example of where it would be appropriate would be a program downloads columns of numbers, adds them up, and then sends the sum back to the server.  In that case, you have numerous different tasks which each take a different amount of time and you don't want to have to wait to finish one task before starting another.

Comment: By the way, you are embarking upon a fantastic journey :-)

Comment: @Rice - What do you mean by `embarking upon a fantastic journey`?

Answer (score 7):

```
Sub Main()
    Console.Write("Hello World!")
End Sub
```

If you really must print one character at a time, you could write:

```
Sub Main()
    dim s as string = "Hello World!"
    dim i as integer
    for i=0 to s.length-1
        Console.Write(s(i))
    end for
End Sub
```

Comment: The code with the original question is set to print one letter of the expression at a time.  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You have brought light to my day!

Comment: Might I suggest the use of inline variable declarations `for i as integer = 0 to s.length - 1`.

Comment: Correct -- but *why* does it print them scrambled? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of parallel execution is that they are done in parallel, not sequentially.  Parallel execution doesn't make sense for this task because order does matter very much.

With asynchronous/parallel execution, each task is split to run in parallel with others and does not wait on any prior tasks to complete.  In your case, some of the later-queued tasks are completing before ones that were queued before them and that is reordering the letters in seemingly random order.

Comment: So parallel executed work items are never re-ordered or ordered?

Comment: As soon as you begin a task using `Parallel`, it's essentially on its own.  It completes when it completes and is independent of all of the other parallel tasks.

Comment: @SpiffySponge: More important than order here is the fact that the actions have to run *sequentially*.

Comment: The point of Parallel.For is that it is very easy to make errors that are hard to detect when you write your program to do several things at once.  With Parallel.For, the .net framework does a lot of the work for you.  However, in this case, you don't want to print all the letters at the same time because they have to be printed in order.  That's why I answered you, `Console.Write("Hello World!")`

Comment: @Daniel - But can't we control the parameters of the Parallel.For execution?

Comment: Absolutely, but doing things such as setting the max degree of parallelism to 1 so that your tasks run sequentially makes using `Parallel.For` pointless.

Comment: @Daniel - Then why is such an option present?